# Post data using webapi in Knockout js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, asp.net-web-api

How to Post data using Web API in `Knockout JS`.

When I post the data, it gives mn Bad Request Error. . .

I have the following `ViewModel`

```
 function StudentViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.StudentID = ko.observable("");
            self.Name = ko.observable("");
            self.Age = ko.observable("");


            var Student = {
                StudentID: self.StudentID,
                Name: self.Name,
                Age: self.Age
            };

            self.Student = ko.observable();
            self.Students = ko.observableArray();

            var baseUri = '@ViewBag.ApiUrl';
            $.getJSON(baseUri, self.Students);
            self.create = function () {
                if (Student.Name() != "" && Student.Age() != "") {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: baseUri,
                        cache: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        data: ko.toJSON(Student),
                        success: function (data) {
                            // alert('added');
                            self.Students.push(data);
                            self.Name("");
                            self.Age("");
                        }
                    }).fail(function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
                        alert(err);
                    });
                }
                else {
                    alert('Please Enter All the Values !!');
                }
            };
```

**Update:**

here is the controller action

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostStudent(Student student)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Students.Add(student);
                db.SaveChanges();

                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, student);
                response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = student.StudentID }));
                return response;
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }
```

Comment: How does your controller action look like?

Comment: Looks like your POST is reaching the controller but the model data is invalid. Try (a) viewing the actual HTTP request that your app is sending and (b) use something like Fiddler to test sending a POST request, and see if there is any difference.

Comment: Should you be referencing self.Student in this line "data: ko.toJSON(Student)"? When debugging in VS you can also check the ModelState to see specifically what errors it has. Debugging will also help you see if everything is mapping correctly to the Student object.

Comment: See if this helps though Angular - [Using AngularJS to send parameters to Web API](http://humblebee.me/2014/01/12/using-angularjs-to-send-parameters-to-web-api/)

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors in your viewModel.

1. In $.ajax you should convert json object to string, use JSON.stringify.
2. Pass url via ViewBag it is very bad idea, declare it as static, or pass in ViewModel on creation.

So, your $.ajax should looks like this:

```
var submitData = ko.toJSON(Student);
$.ajax({
    url: baseUri,
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(submitData),
    success: function (data) {
        // alert('added');
        self.Students.push(data);
        self.Name("");
        self.Age("");
    }
```